# Using DynamoDB to replace logfiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging

We are hosting our services in AWS beanstalk managed instances.  That is forcing us to move away from files based logging to use database based logging.

Is DynamoDB a good choice for replacing file based logging.  If so, what should be the primary key.  I thought of using timestamp but multiple messages may be logged by the same service within the same timeStamp so that might not be reliable.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use DynamoDB to store logs. You'll be paying for throughput and space needlessly.

Amazon CloudWatch has built-in logging capabilities.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

Another alternative is a dedicated logging service such as Loggly which is cloud-based and can receive logs in many common formats, plus they have an API to send custom logs. In the web-based console, you can search and filter through the logs.

Comment: Totally agree about that, just look through DynamoDB pricing model before use.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, why don't you use cloudwatch? I ended up writing a whole app to consolidate logs across ec2 instances in a beanstalk app, then last year AWS opened up cloudwatch as a service, so I junked my stuff. You tell cloudwatch where your logs are on the instance, give it a log group and stream name, and all your logs are consolidated in one spot, in cloudwatch. You can also run alarms off them using the standard AWS setup. It's pretty slick, and easy - don't have to write a front end to do lookups, it's already there.

Don't know what you're using for logging - we are a node.js shop, used winston for logging, and there is a nice NPM module that works with Winston to log automatically, called winston-cloudwatch.